# AWS Cloudfront with S3 Bucket configured to redirect from naked domain to www

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to get my naked URL to redirect to www subdomain.

The current website is up and running serving the content from an S3 bucket via cloudfront: `https://www.gauntface.com`.

Now I'm trying to set up a redirect for `http://gauntface.com` to `https://www.gauntface.com`.

I've created a new S3 bucket with no contents but set up with static site hosting and redirects to https://www.gauntface.com. The URL provided by the S3 bucket works correctly and redirects.

I then tried setting up cloud front to serve content from this new bucket but I get an `Access Denied` error. I'm getting the impression that cloudfront will access the S3 bucket via Rest API meaning it ignore the static site hosting configuration.

So next I'm trying to set up a custom domain to use the S3 bucket directly but so far my CNAME record in namecheap doesn't seem to work and I fear that it won't support SSL.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: There are two ways of using S3 with CF: one is by using S3 in website mode, and second through Origin Access Identity. If you use the former, you have to provide url of the bucket to CF.

Comment: I wrote an indepth article after struggling with this. https://medium.com/@kylecalicast/production-level-static-sites-in-aws-39573c9bf4d5 
My setup is a private S3 bucket to Cloudfront and even has HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

This was largely thanks to Marcin in the comments.

From what I can gather, setting cloudfront distrbution to have an `Origin Domain Name` set to the S3 Bucket will cause cloudfront to use the rest API to access files in the bucket, which in this case do not exist.

Changing `Origin Domain Name` to the endpoint provided by the S3 bucket > Properties > Static Website Hosting will make cloudfront make network requests to the buckets static server meaning it'll receive and forward the redirect response.